# Rails app for MongoDB administration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, administration

i'm looking for a MongoDB administration tool written in ruby (rails, sinatra ...) that behaves like phpMyAdmin but isn't written in PHP or any other language. on my local machine I use RockMongo, which is rather nice, but PHP...

the problem is, I don't want to install fastcgi PHP on our server just for the database administration...

thanks in advance. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [Mongo3](https://github.com/derailed/mongo3) which is Ruby, or check out the list of [MongoDB Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) from the official docs.

Comment: That's very useful info, ... don't mind if someone say "not constructive" for me that's full Q&A format !!!